# ModelState.IsValid = false MVC 4 Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi, I'm kinda new to MVC and Entity Framework, so I can't figure out how to resolve this problem. I searched (trust me) for an awnser but got no results.
I'm trying to login on my project using Entity Framework. The thing is I added:

`public string Confirmar_contraseña { get; set; }`

to "Users" model to verify if passwords are equal or not (when you are in the register screen)

Model:

```c#
namespace MundialDeFutbol.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using DataAnnotationsExtensions;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public partial class Usuarios
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El nick (nombre de usuario) es obligatoio")]
    [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "El nombre de usuario debe contener entre 3 y 15 caracteres")]
    public string Nick { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "La contraseña es obligatoria")]
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 4, ErrorMessage = "La contraseña debe contener entre 4 y 10 caracteres")]
    public string Contraseña { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [Compare("Contraseña", ErrorMessage = "Las contraseñas no coinciden")]
    public string Confirmar_contraseña { get; set; }
    public int Tipo_de_usuario { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```c#
@using MundialDeFutbol.Models
@using System.Web.Optimization
@model Usuarios

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<h2>Login</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Usuarios", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", @style = "margin-top: 20px;" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Nick" class="col-sm-2 control-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nick)</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nick, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Nombre de usuario" })
            <strong>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nick, null, new { @class = "text-danger", @style = "display: block; margin-top: 10px;" })
            </strong>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Contraseña" class="col-sm-2 control-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contraseña)</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Contraseña, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Escribe contraseña", @type = "password" })
            <strong>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contraseña, null, new { @class = "text-danger", @style = "display: block; margin-top: 10px;" })
            </strong>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Controller

```c#
namespace MundialDeFutbol.Controllers
{
    public class UsuariosController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Usuarios/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Registrar()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Registrar(Usuarios usuario)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var ctx = new MundialDBEntities();
                ctx.Usuarios.Add(usuario);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
            }

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(Usuarios usuario)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(usuario.Nick, false);
                //This needs to be completed I think
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

There are some words in spanish, sorry for that. The point is I used "Confirmar_contraseña" as a auxiliar attribute on database entity model, just to confirm the user type the same password, but when I try to login, ModelState returns false, I don't know why.

Comment: Show your model and the actionmethod where the modelstate claims to be invalid.

Comment: More code please! You've only asked half a question. 'You added x to verify passwords but .....'

Comment: Im on it, it's really hard to use this editor -.-

Comment: Can you add code for the Controller please?

Comment: Are you missing code for `Confirmar_contraseña` as the comparison field in the View?

Comment: Just a guess but `ñ`in your variable name could cause issues in Javascript (willl be solved in ECMAScript 6) and depending on your encoding when posting to the server...

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz, I used that in "Register" action, now I want to login and I don't know why ModelState returns false.

Obviously this field has nothing to do with the database table "Users" which structure is like

    [Id]              INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Nick]            VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    [Contraseña]      VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    [Tipo de usuario] INT          DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check what the ModelState errors are, add the following in the post action method and examine the `errors` property

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
  var errors = this.ModelState.Keys.SelectMany(key => this.ModelState[key].Errors);
  ....
```

Comment: You need to expand the list to see what they are

Comment: [Errors 2](http://puu.sh/8YV78.png)

It says "Passwords don't match", just like the DataAnnotation I used in the model, but I'm trying to login, not to register I don't get it

Comment: You need 2 separate models, one to register that includes both the password and password confirmation properties, and a separate model for login that has the password only. Because you are using a model that includes both, when it is passed to the controller action, the model binder sees that the password does not match the confirmation (which is null because its not even in the view) and a model state error is generated.

Comment: So I'll need a LoginController and a LogoutController?

Comment: Can be same controller, but different action methods, for example `public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model) {...` and `public ActionResult Login (LoginViewModel model){...`